# How to overwrite remote git repository with a new local project

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I don't have the permissions to delete/create a new repository so I would like clean out the one I have access to and overwrite it with a new project I started locally.  I cannot find the instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add the repo as a remote to your new project, then use `git push -f` to destroy the repo's history and replace it with your own history.

That works equally well whether you're removing a single commit or replacing everything with a new history.

Comment: Thank you!  In case some other git noob comes around, these are the exact steps I took:
In the new local repository:
`git init` , `git add --all`, `git remote add origin <remote url>`, `git commit -m "some comment"`, `git push -f origin master`

Comment: @insitumatt This should really be the accepted answer and not a comment. As an additional note, if others have already pulled master and need to update they should run `git fetch --all` to download the latest then `git reset --hard origin/master` to overwrite everything.

Comment: @insitumatt This fixed mine as well, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works. However, downside of this approach is that if you have cloned repositories, you have to re-clone them. Otherwise getting `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. Is there any solution for this?